# Magento Product Page redirection

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Which controller in Magento do I need to override if I want to redirect a certain product view page to another url?

I'd like to use the following code for redirection. Is there any more Magento-like way of doing it?

```
if($this->getProductId() == 10) {
    header("Location: /mymodule");
    die();  
}
```

Comment: every product is set to redirect in database table. I think you should edit the particular table where all redirections of the products is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. Might not be the best one but it works:

Observer.php:

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer  {
    public function redirect(){
        //request object
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        //only redirect in the frontend/catalog
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        if(in_array($request->getModuleName(), array("catalog")) && $storeId != 0) {
            $response = Mage::app()->getResponse();
            $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
            //check the product id
            if($params[id] == 10) {
                return $response->setRedirect("/mymodule", 301)->sendHeaders();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the config.xml in the global/events section:

```
<controller_action_predispatch> 
    <observers> 
        <namespace_mymodule_observer>
           <type>singleton</type>
           <class>namespace_mymodule/observer</class> 
           <method>redirect</method>
        </namespace_mymodule_observer> 
    </observers> 
</controller_action_predispatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento Admin has a feature for this under ***Catalog > URL Rewrite Management***. Create a new product rewrite with these steps:

1. Click the *Add URL Rewrite* button at top right.
2. Select “Custom” from *Create URL Rewrite*.
3. Choose the appropriate *Store*.
4. Set *Request Path* to something like this `catalog/product/view/id/10` (assuming 10 is the ID of your product).
5. Set *Target Path* to whatever route or URL you want to send the request to.
6. Set *Redirect* to probably “Temporary (302)”.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm rather looking for a coded realization than a configured approach. Therefore, I'd like to know which controller to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better approach is to actually utilize the observer event since all you need is included here already. Also, the answer does not differentiate between products and categories since `in_array($request->getModuleName(), array("catalog"))` would be true for both.

```
class Namespace_Mymodule_Model_Observer {

    public function redirect(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $actionName = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName();
        $productId = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getRequest()->getParam('id');

        if($actionName == 'catalog_product_view' && $productId == 10) {

            $response = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getResponse();
            $response->setRedirect('/mymodule', 301)->sendHeaders();

        }
    }
}
```